# Caching in iOS application and RESTful web service

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, caching

I'm currently working on a iOS application that consumes data from a RESTful remote web service. Are there any common design principles for implementing a - local or remote - caching strategy in this context?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use database to save your response Or `.plist` I can suggest you a better idea to use `NSCachedURLResponse` and `NSCache`.

You can use these classes to store your web service response. I don't know if you have already tried bean classes and reuse those objects to show data.

Hope this will work.